# Using consecutive D3.html() methods to concatenate html; rather than replace

Tags: javascript, html, select, d3.js

I want to use d3.html() to add html to a div selector. And then I'd like to use it a second time, to append more html.

The problem is, when you use d3.html() on a selection, you completely replace the html attached to the object selector.

Is there a way to use html to append more html, rather than entirely replace the prior html?

Comment: Something like `d3.html(d3.html() + foobar)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
d3.select('selector').html(function() {
  return d3.select(this).html() + *newHtml*;
});
```